# Why is the movement of a Chess King aperiodic?

Tags: markov-chains

Imagine we have a king by itself on a chess board, making random moves around the board. Although it is apparently aperiodic, wouldn't the corresponding Markov chain to the King's movements be *periodic* since the King could only return to a square *i* on the board at moves 2,4,6 ... etc. (great common denominator of 2) after initially being at the square?

By definition, aperiodic chains have return times to *i* with a g.c.d. of 1.

Comment: Kings can move diagonally can't they? So you can get a cycle of length 3 by doing left, up, diagonally down to the right?

Comment: A king can move ***up***, ***right***, and then ***down-left***, returning to the same place in 3 moves.

Comment: A king can return to its original square in any number of moves greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mathematics is correct but your understanding of the rules of chess is not.  A king on any square that is not on the edge of the board can move to any of eight squares: the four that share a common edge with the one he's on and the four that share only a common vertex.